# Unable to send session created in python to react

Tags: cors, cherrypy

My backend runs in a docker container and my frontend runs in a different container and this is load balanced by traefik. I am unable to send the session created in the backed to the frontend.

my backend url - http://test-backend.localhost/api/test
my frontend url - http://test-frontend.localhost/#/one

```py
class Test(object):
    exposed = True

    @property
    def db(self):
        return cherrypy.request.db    
   

    @cherrypy.tools.accept(media='text/plain')
    def GET(self):
        cherrypy.session['something'] = "test"
        return Service.get_service(self)

    @cherrypy.tools.json_in()
    @cherrypy.tools.json_out()    
    def POST(self):
        cherrypy.session['something'] = "john"
        cookie = cherrypy.request.cookie
        if 'uid' in cookie.keys():
            uid = cookie['uid'].value
        if 'uid' not in cookie.keys():
            uid = 'uid' + datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
            cookie = cherrypy.response.cookie            
            cookie['uid'] = uid
            cookie['uid']['expires'] = 3600
            cookie['uid']['path'] = '/'
            cookie['uid']['secure'] = True
        
        # Manually set the session cookie in the response headers
        cherrypy.response.headers['Set-Cookie'] = str(cookie)


        input_json = cherrypy.request.json
        print("session is", cherrypy.session.id)

        print(input_json)       
      
        # Validate the Request JSON data
        # try:
        #     schema = HitSchema()
        #     validated_data = schema.load(query_string)
        #     return Service.post_service(self, query_string, cherrypy.response.cookie)

        # except ValidationError as e:
        #     cherrypy.response.status = 400
        #     return {"error": str(e)}
        # Add the appropriate return statement here
        return "POST request processed successfully"        


    def OPTIONS(self):
        # Handle preflight request
        cherrypy.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] 
           = 'true'
        cherrypy.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
        cherrypy.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET, POST'
        cherrypy.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Content-Type, Authorization, Accept, X-Requested-With, Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Headers'
```

my frontend code looks like below.

```js
const mutation = useMutation((newTodo: any) => {
    return axios.post('http://test-backend.localhost/api/test', newTodo);
  });
```

I tried like this as well

```
 const mutation = useMutation((newTodo: any) => {
    return axios.post('http://test-backend.localhost/api/hit', newTodo, {
      withCredentials: true,
    });
  });
```

When I send a POST request from frontend to backend, session is created in the backend but cookie it not set in the browser.

when I try with credentials=true in firefox, I get the below error

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at ‘http://test-backend.localhost/api/test’. (Reason: Credential is not supported if the CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ is ‘*’)
```

Comment: Necessary conditions for the browser to honour that `Set-Cookie` response header are 1) the request must be credentialed and 2) the resource must be properly configured for CORS (i.e. allow the origin of the client with credentials). Neither of those conditions are fulfilled by your code.

Comment: I tried to use withCredentials: true in the frontend and also used cherrypy.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] 
           = 'true' in cherrypy but I get this error

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: (Reason: Credential is not supported if the CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ is ‘*’)

Comment: Yes. [You cannot use the wildcard for credentialed requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#credentialed_requests_and_wildcards). `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` should contain, not `*`, but the exact Web origin of your frontend.